# Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpini_set() in /home/somefile.php

Tags: php, hosting, ini

These are lines at the top of file

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //300 seconds = 5 minutes 
ini_set('memory_limit', '256 M'); 
ini_set('post_max_size', '64 M');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: there are no disable functions there   --

Comment: Isn't there by chance anything like `<?phpini_set(...)` in your code, right? Or maybe some unicode hidden char that it can't interprete as valid newline...